# Oozie job stuck at START action in PREP state

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have an Oozie job that I start from java client which gets stuck at START action and it says that it is RUNNING, but the START node is in PREP state.

Why is that and how to fix the problem?

The Oozie workflow contains only one java action. The Hadoop version on the cluster is 2.4.0, and Oozie on cluster is 4.0.0.

Here is the workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.2' name='java-filecopy-wf'>
<start to='java1'/>
    <action name='java1'>
    <java>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>default</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>           
        <main-class>testingoozieclient.Client</main-class>
        <capture-output/>
    </java>
    <ok to="end" />
    <error to="fail" />
</action>
<kill name="fail">
    <message>Java failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]
        </message>
</kill>
<end name='end' />
```

Here is the java client

```
    OozieClient oozieClient = new OozieClient(args[0]);

    Properties conf = oozieClient.createConfiguration();
    conf.setProperty(OozieClient.APP_PATH, args[1]);

    conf.setProperty("nameNode", args[2]);
    conf.setProperty("jobTracker", args[3]);

    String jobId = null;

    try{
        jobId = oozieClient.run(conf);
    }
    catch(OozieClientException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }
```

Since I tried this a couple of times, there are now 5,6 workflows that all have RUNNING as state, but when I look it through the web interface I can see that all of them are stuck on START node in PREP state?

---

After some of submitted workflows got killed I was able to start another workflow. This time the workflow goes from start to java action, but gets stuck in the java action in a similar way - it stays in the PREP state.

Here's what the log looks like

```
2015-06-22 17:54:37,366  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[java-filecopy-wf] JOB[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2015-06-22 17:54:37,367  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[java-filecopy-wf] JOB[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2015-06-22 17:54:37,367  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[java-filecopy-wf] JOB[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2015-06-22 17:54:37,426  INFO ActionEndXCommand:539 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[java-filecopy-wf] JOB[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] end executor for wf action 0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W with wf job 0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W
2015-06-22 17:54:37,676  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[java-filecopy-wf] JOB[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@java1] Start action [0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@java1] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2015-06-22 17:54:38,316  INFO JavaActionExecutor:539 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[java-filecopy-wf] JOB[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@java1] addShareLib: using FileSystem hdfs://master:8020
2015-06-22 17:54:38,501  WARN JavaActionExecutor:542 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[java-filecopy-wf] JOB[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@java1] credentials is null for the action
2015-06-22 17:54:38,640  INFO JavaActionExecutor:539 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[java-filecopy-wf] JOB[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@java1] addShareLib: using FileSystem hdfs://master:8020
```

[image]

---

This morning I found that the job is in state SUSPENDED, start node is OK, but the Java node is in START-RETRY, with the following error -   JA006: Call From master02.novalocal/192.168.111.52 to master02.novalocal:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

I should probably emphasize that the Oozie works on the same machine as Resource manager, so it's strange that it tries to start the workflow on the same machine, but says that connection has failed.

Here is the job log from Oozie:

```
    2015-06-22 17:54:37,366  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[java-filecopy-wf] JOB[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2015-06-22 17:54:37,367  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[java-filecopy-wf] JOB[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2015-06-22 17:54:37,367  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[java-filecopy-wf] JOB[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2015-06-22 17:54:37,426  INFO ActionEndXCommand:539 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[java-filecopy-wf] JOB[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] end executor for wf action 0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W with wf job 0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W
2015-06-22 17:54:37,676  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[java-filecopy-wf] JOB[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@java1] Start action [0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@java1] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2015-06-22 17:54:38,316  INFO JavaActionExecutor:539 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[java-filecopy-wf] JOB[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@java1] addShareLib: using FileSystem hdfs://master01.novalocal:8020
2015-06-22 17:54:38,501  WARN JavaActionExecutor:542 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[java-filecopy-wf] JOB[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@java1] credentials is null for the action
2015-06-22 17:54:38,640  INFO JavaActionExecutor:539 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[java-filecopy-wf] JOB[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@java1] addShareLib: using FileSystem hdfs://master01.novalocal:8020
2015-06-22 20:05:33,340  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[java-filecopy-wf] JOB[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000030-150619153616589-oozie-oozi-W@java1] Error starting action [java1]. ErrorType [TRANSIENT], ErrorCode [  JA006], Message [  JA006: Call From master02.novalocal/192.168.111.52 to master02.novalocal:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException:   JA006: Call From master02.novalocal/192.168.111.52 to master02.novalocal:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertExceptionHelper(ActionExecutor.java:412)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertException(ActionExecutor.java:392)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:837)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:988)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:215)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:60)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:280)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:326)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:255)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Call From master02.novalocal/192.168.111.52 to master02.novalocal:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor98.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.getDelegationToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getDelegationToken(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:282)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.getDelegationToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.getRMDelegationToken(YarnClientImpl.java:452)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ResourceMgrDelegate.getDelegationToken(ResourceMgrDelegate.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getDelegationToken(YARNRunner.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.getDelegationToken(Cluster.java:400)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$16.run(JobClient.java:1203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$16.run(JobClient.java:1200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.getDelegationToken(JobClient.java:1199)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.createJobClient(HadoopAccessorService.java:377)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.createJobClient(JavaActionExecutor.java:1031)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:786)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:735)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1381)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: can you pls add the error log stated in the oozie.?

Comment: I would, but the strangest thing is that I don't get any errors. When I look at JobLog in web interface it is completely empty? Where should I look for the errors?

Comment: go to job log and get job log! or try in the historyserver!! i think oozie successfully submitted the job over to hadoop!! pls check the yarn logs in history server.

Comment: I have edited my question, please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet your map-reduce cluster must be running out of slots. Check out how many map slots are configured.

Also try to figure out if the service is up on port 8032. You could use the command sudo netstat -netulp | grep 8032. If there is no output returned then the service is down. And you also can check connectivity using nmap or telnet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is that possible if I'm not running any MR jobs? I'm just starting a simple java class that prints out some text, just to check if my client works.

Comment: Oozie runs its jobs on Map-Reduce cluster so first of all you should make sure that your Map-Reduce cluster is up and running, having enough map slots (at least two for running one job).

Comment: Try to sort if the service is up on port 8032. You could use the command 
sudo netstat -netulp | grep 8032. If there is no output returned then the service is down. And you also can check connectivity using nmap or telnet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems that it uses a non standard (8050) port. I'm guessing that the problem is that too many jobs were started (as you suggested) and that caused choking. Now I'm getting a ClassNotFound exception, but it seems that workflow is running, so I'm accepting your answer, based on the answer itself and the last comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

Pls check the ports in job.properties
This is usually problem with namenode and jobtracker ports.
Make sure your jobtracker port is correct in job.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

The major reason for an oozie job getting stuck in PREP state (eventually moving to START_MANUAL state), is **misconfiguration of Hadoop services ports**.

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:9000
jobTracker=10.71.71.15:8032
```

If you are running YARN, then the default port for jobtracker is same as resource manager's port.

Also, try to fix other port issues like `jobhistoryserver's port` (as mentioned in oozie Error message).

Answer (score 0):

command:

```
netstat -ntpl | grep 8032
```

See if the port number is open.
If it is not, you need to start the service with the port number.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was due to YARN being stopped. I started it and the workflow made progress.