# Oozie job status stuck to PREP

Tags: hive, sqoop, oozie, oozie-workflow

I am trying to run oozie workflow containing sqoop and hive jobs but on running status of Job become PREP and after a while it convert into START_RETRY as shown in picture
[image]

my workflow.xml file is

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5" name="simpleWF">

    <start to="sqoop-import-A"/>
        <action name="sqoop-import-A">
            <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
                <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
                <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                <configuration>
                    <property>
                       <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                       <value>default</value>
                    </property>
                </configuration>
                <command>import --connect 
                   jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera/movie_lens --username 
                   root --password cloudera --table ratings --target-dir 
                   /user/cloudera/Movie_AY377330 -m 1</command>
           </sqoop>
           <ok to="sqoop-import-B"/>
           <error to="fail"/>
       </action>
       <action name="sqoop-import-B">
           <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
                <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
                <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                <configuration>
                   <property>
                        <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                        <value>default</value>
                   </property>
                </configuration>
                <command>import --connect 
                jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera/movie_lens --username root 
                --password cloudera --table movie --target-dir 
               /user/cloudera/Movie_AY3773301 -m 1</command>
            </sqoop>
            <ok to="sqoop-import-C"/>
            <error to="fail"/>
        </action>
        <action name="sqoop-import-C">
            <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
                 <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
                 <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                  <configuration>
                     <property>
                         <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                         <value>default</value>
                     </property>
                  </configuration>
                  <command>sqoop import --connect 
                  jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera/movie_lens --username 
                  root --password cloudera --table tags --target-dir 
                  /user/cloudera/Movie_AY3773302 -m 1</command>
             </sqoop>
             <ok to="hive-node"/>
             <error to="fail"/>
        </action>

        <action name="hive-node">
            <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
                <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
                <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                <job-xml>hive-site.xml</job-xml>
                <configuration>
                       <property>
                             <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                             <value>${queueName}</value>
                       </property>              
                </configuration>
                <script>hive1.hql</script>
            </hive>
            <ok to="hive-node-2"/>
            <error to="fail"/>
     </action>
     <action name="hive-node-2">
           <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
           <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
           <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
           <job-xml>hive-site.xml</job-xml>
           <configuration>
                <property>
                     <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                     <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>              
           </configuration>
           <script>hive2.hql</script>
           <param>OUTPUT_PATH1=${outputPath1}</param>
      </hive>
      <ok to="hive-node-3"/>
      <error to="fail"/>
   </action>
   <action name="hive-node-3">
       <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
       <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
       <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>        
       <job-xml>hive-site.xml</job-xml>
       <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>              
        </configuration>
        <script>hive3.hql</script>
        <param>OUTPUT_PATH2=${outputPath2}</param>
     </hive>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>

<kill name="fail">
    <message>error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>

<end name="end"/>
```

and my job.properties file is

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:50300
queueName=default
exampleRoot=example
folder= test
outputPath1=
outputPath2=
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.libpath=/user/oozie/share/lib
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${exampleRoot}
```

I have found a similar question at [Oozie job stuck at START action in PREP state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978418/oozie-job-stuck-at-start-action-in-prep-state)  and try to solve issue but no idea how to do it.

I know that something is wrong with my namenode or jobtracker address.

I can access my namenode in browser by localhost:50070

After a while the job is suspended with error

```
JA009: Failed on local exception: 
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-
group tag did not match expected tag.; Host Details : local host is: 
"quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "localhost":8088;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you able to access hdfs files using command `hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:8020/` or `hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:50070`? put the namenode in job.properties as relevant

Comment: I am able to access it with     hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:8020/

Comment: So, before this have you run a single workflow using oozie in that particular machine and was it success? if succeeded that time, then it is an error from your properties and workflow.xml side otherwise first check the proxy hosts, users and groups, as well as the database properties in the oozie-site.xml and later run two of the test of database connectivity and access to the shareliblist by commands bin/oozie-setup.sh db create -run & 
bin/oozie admin -shareliblist -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie, hope this will help you, thanks.